# Apache's localhost base URL displays Laravel welcome screen [UBUNTU 16.04]

Tags: apache, laravel

When I access `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, I should be displayed the index.html default page from apache.

[image: apache's default welcome screen]

However, when I access it, it displays the Laravel welcoming screen.

[image: what apache displays when accessing <code>localhost</code>]

- I do have some Laravel projects under `/var/www/html`, indeed.

But it seems Apache is confused as to what page to display in the root directory, displaying Laravel's welcome screen instead of the usual `index.html`.

This would not be much of a problem, but it also happens that, whenever accessing any other project which is not Laravel-based, i'm faced with Laravel's 404 screen.

Any ideas as to what happened here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minutes after typing this question, i found the answer myself.

I deleted the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`, which sets the default response for `localhost` request.

So, Apache took Laravel's page as the default for answering any request to the server.

[Here's a gist I made for recovering this file.](https://gist.github.com/rbenvenuto/9629df77d26ae964897f64b86db2936b)